# What is the best second lane for a support main?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I have been a main support the whole time in league of legends and I am now stranded in plat V. It seems that from here it gets very hard to carry the game as a main support. My question is: What lane is the best lane to switch to as a main support?

I hope somebody can help me out and can give some suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean what other role might you be suited for, given that you're good at support? The answer is: It depends. For me it's top. For someone else maybe it's jungle. The roles all play significantly differently. I don't think this is answerable.

Comment: I feel top and jungle more so are most like support. As support you obviously aren't a huge part of your teams damage and are usually the tanky/utility person. The same can go for jungle and somewhat top depending on which champion you pick.

Comment: Supportive junglers can sometimes be nice but are harder to play.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hard to switch to another lane after only playing a certain one but if you've played support there are 2 roles you could play to carry.

You only have to ask the question: Why did you play support? If you know the answer to this question you can chose a lane which has some of the points why you chose the support.

The main job of a supporter in League is keeping a good overview of the game and getting kills or protecting the ADC. So basically what you want is a role that also has these jobs and there are two of those in particular. (Of course overview and adc protection is important for everyone but it's the supporter who should do most of it).

**Jungler**

You could switch to a jungler role, since you also have great overview of the game, you can ward the whole map and you can protect the ADC or hunt the enemy ADC down especially if you are a bruiser. Your main jobs as jungler are: ganking, jungling, counterjungling, warding and objective control. The good thing is that ganking, objective control and warding are also a big thing in a support role.

**ADC**
Of course you could also play AD Carry since you always lane with one. That's the option I chose because I've learned a lot from supporting an adc. Positioning and awareness shouldn't be a problem if you are a former support player. The biggest problem with this role is the farming. Many support players just don't know how to cs properly. And while you might outfarm low-mid elo, most platinum players with a main role in either top/mid or adc can farm pretty well.

So Basically it depends on the reason you played support. Is it the protection, is it the awareness or maybe the mechanical skill. You have to find a new Main champion and a new Main Lane. And of course this doesn't have to be ADC or Jungler. You can also play Top or Mid but those lanes have very little to do with supporters.

I personally started to play ADC but I realised one thing: Learing a new role at high elo is harder than mastering the one you already can play quite well.

Comment: From most people I talk to, ADC seems like the next role a lot of supports master since they already have such a close relationship with them.  The playstyle is very different, but the laning knowledge is very close.